# Memory Management in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I am a little confused while using NSDictionary. I have a array (*nameArray*), I add that array to a Dictionary (*nameDict*) and finally I add this dictionary to another dictionary (*requestDict*).

```
NSMutableArray *nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"abcd",@"lmnop",@"xyz",@"pqr", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *nameDict = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:nameArray,@"name", nil];
NSDictionary *requestDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:nameDict];
```

When I remove objects from nameDict , requestDict is not affected.

```
[nameDict removeAllObjects]
```

So far so good. But my query is when I remove objects from nameArray why responseDict is affected.

`[nameArray removeAllObjects];`

Why nameArray still has objects. Shouldn't it have been deallocated as soon as I remove objects from nameDict. Please help me understand if I am missing something here.

What happens if I set nameArray to nil in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `nameDict` and `requestDict` have a reference to the single array pointed to by `nameArray`. Changes made to `nameArray` are seen by both dictionaries.

When you did `[nameArray removeAllObjects]` you see the change to the array in both dictionaries because both dictionaries are referencing the one copy of the mutable array.

If you set `nameArray` to `nil`, nothing happens. Both dictionaries still have a reference to the mutable array.

Comment: But I never made a reference between nameArray to requestDict. Instead I added nameArray to nameDict. Shouldn't requestDict have the reference to nameDict and nameDict has a reference to nameArray?

Comment: Sure you do. `nameDict` contains `nameArray`. Then you create a copy of `nameDict` as `requestDict`. This means that `requestDict` has a reference to the exact same objects (shallow copy) as `nameDict`.

Comment: Now I can see what is happening... Thank You...:)

Comment: That being said, how can I implement this if I want nameArray to clear all its values . For example I am setting nameDict in a loop. I add nameArray into the dict. In the second loop I want nameArray should not have any objects.

Comment: Calling `removeAllObjects` will remove all objects from the array. And since both dictionaries are referencing the same array, the objects will disappear from them as well.

Comment: setting nameArray to nil and allocating it again works but is it right way to do it

Comment: Doing that will have no effect on the array in the dictionaries.